# How to solve (in)equality of three variables with trigonometric solutions

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, polynomials, uvw, buffalo-way

I'm working through a set of inequality problems and I'm stuck on the following question:

> Find all sets of solutions for which $$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2=3(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a)$$ holds. Note that $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Firstly, one can easily see that when $a=b=c$ then the equality holds: $$\text{LHS}=(a^2+a^2+a^2)^2=(3a^2)^2=9a^4$$ and $$\text{RHS}=3(a^4+a^4+a^4)=3(3a^4)=9a^4.$$

A hint is given to use the substitutions $a=x+2ty$, $b=y+2tz$ and $c=x+2tz$ for real $t$. The LHS is rather nice in that it simplifies to $$(4t(xy+xz+yz)+(1+4t^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2))^2$$ but I can't find a similar simplification for the RHS. I guess this is a type of *uvw* question but I don't know where to start.

There are actually four sets of solutions: $$a=b=c,$$ $$\frac{a}{\sin^2\frac{4\pi}7}=\frac{b}{\sin^2\frac{2\pi}7}=\frac{c}{\sin^2\frac{\pi}7},$$ $$\frac{b}{\sin^2\frac{4\pi}7}=\frac{c}{\sin^2\frac{2\pi}7}=\frac{a}{\sin^2\frac{\pi}7},$$ and $$\frac{c}{\sin^2\frac{4\pi}7}=\frac{a}{\sin^2\frac{2\pi}7}=\frac{b}{\sin^2\frac{\pi}7}$$ I have no idea how the  trigonometric expressions are obtained. How could the equality be solved?

Comment: i think this is an inequality with $a,b,c>0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint.

Let $b=a+u$,$c=a+v$ and $u=xv$.

Hence, $$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2-3(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a)=\sum_{cyc}(a^4+2a^2b^2-3a^3b)=$$
$$=(u^2-uv+v^2)a^2+(u^3-5u^2v+4uv^2+v^3)a+u^4-3u^3v+2u^2v^2+v^4\geq0$$
because
$$(u^3-5u^2v+4uv^2+v^3)^2-4(u^2-uv+v^2)(u^4-3u^3v+2u^2v^2+v^4)=$$
$$=-3(u^3-u^2v-2u^2+v^3)^2=-3v^6(x^3-x^2-2x+1)^2\leq0.$$
The equality occurs for $x^3-x^2-2x+1=0$,
which gives $$x\in\left\{2\cos\frac{\pi}{7},-2\cos\frac{2\pi}{7},2\cos\frac{3\pi}{7}\right\}.$$
For example, $x=2\cos\frac{\pi}{7}$ gives the following case.
$$\frac{b}{\sin^2\frac{4\pi}7}=\frac{c}{\sin^2\frac{2\pi}7}=\frac{a}{\sin^2\frac{\pi}7}.$$
My solution by $uvw$ see here:
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h6026p5329091

There is also the following nice solution.
https://gbas2010.wordpress.com/2010/01/08/problem-19vasile-cirtoaje/

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
Take the square root of all terms in $\frac{c}{\sin^2\frac{4\pi}7}=\frac{a}{\sin^2\frac{2\pi}7}=\frac{b}{\sin^2\frac{\pi}7}$.
Now you obtain a case of a well known equation: the sine rule.
$\frac {4\pi}7 + \frac {2\pi}7 +\frac {\pi}7= \pi$, so this is a triangle with side lengths $\sqrt a, \sqrt b$ and $\sqrt c$ and angles $\frac {\pi}7, \frac {2\pi}7 $ and $ \frac {4\pi}7$.

Hope you can take it from here!

Comment: But $a$, $b$ and $c$ are reals and why they are all solutions?

Comment: See Dr. Sonnhard Graubner's comment.